jmeter run is showing error which shows SSL Handshake Exception
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2024-08-21 16:21:30 IST
Load time:153
Connect Time:153
Latency:0
Size in bytes:2886
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:2886
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Remote host terminated the handshake


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

I have tried many solutions got from google but couldn't fixed it

Instead of trying "many solutions got from google" you should rather enable debug output of SSL connections
You can do it by adding the next line to JMeter system.properties file
javax.net.debug=all

after JMeter restart you should see a lot of information regarding connection failure and it should allow you to guess which JMeter setting to amend and how exactly to fix the issue.
